# Term for abrupt termination of sedation

Tags: word-request, slang

I'm looking for a word or slang regarding the abrupt awakening from a narcotic's sedation. To be precise, there is a state in which a drug addict abruptly wakes up from the pleasant trance he is experiencing via a loud noise a light flash in his eyes. In this awakening, the pleasant feeling is immediately replaced by pain.

Does anyone know what that term or slang is?

Comment: *Cold turkey** is a common expression for narcotic withdrawal symptoms.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ronald, I didn't know about Cold turkey. But it seems that cold turkey is the result of the good feeling gradually running out. I'm more interested in the artificial sudden withdrawal. For example, when someone is in a pleasant trance and someone else flashes light in their eyes or something really loud awakens them from that trance. That sudden withdrawal is what I'm looking for.

Comment: We would not say awaken here. We say: to **come out of or come down from a drug-induced state**. However, it needn't just be drug addicts.  A person can be napping and then be jolted awake by a light or noise. The word crash is used to mean the end of the drug-induced state: I'm crashing, man. And finally, sedation is a medical term not a druggie term.

Answer (score 0):

It's not specific to your context, but *rude awakening* is a common phrase for something that causes a sudden need to face reality.

[Wiktionary *rude awakening*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rude_awakening)

> An unexpected discovery of an undesirable fact, especially one shattering high hopes or signifying the end of a comfortable situation.

Comment: Thanks, Jack, this is very similar to what I'm looking for. But not quite it. Honestly, I don't know if the word I'm looking for exists or not, but I suspect it should. Police flashlights and sirens seem like a common thing to wake the drug addicts up. And the biology dictates that they must go from pleasant to unpleasant state in a heartbeat. They must have come up with a name or slang for it.

Comment: No, that's not how drugs work.  You can't remove the effects of a drug by making a loud noise.

Answer (score 0):

- Although it does not give any indication of the nature of the cause of the abrupt awakening, [Ronald Sole](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/313512/term-for-abrupt-termination-of-sedation#comment587684_313512) is right in the sense that this likely comes closest to what you want:

  **cold turkey**:

  > The abrupt and complete cessation of taking a drug to which one is addicted.
  > <sup>[lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/definition/cold_turkey)</sup>

  > Abrupt and complete withdrawal from the use of an addictive substance, as a narcotic drug, alcohol, or tobacco.
  > <sup>[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/cold-turkey)</sup>
- To suggest someone is abruptly taken out of a spell caused by something (like a drug-induced high), you could use the idiom '**snap out of**':

  > Suddenly recover
  > <sup>[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/snap--out--of)</sup>

  > To stop being in or to cause (someone) to stop being in (an unhappy condition or mood, a daydream, etc.)
  > <sup>[merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snap%20out%20of)</sup>

  Despite these definitions, the word 'snap' suggests that this change is indeed sudden.

Comment: When I hung out with acid-heads and speed freaks 50 years ago, people talked of 'coming down' from a drug 'high', and also an experience or even a remark that caused a good or euphoric feeling (drug-induced or natural) to vanish was said to be a 'bring down'. As has been said, these things did not usually happen in an instant.

Comment: A euphoric mood could be dissipated in an instant. Person A: Hey man! We're all high! Person B: But the house is on fire/the cat is dead/the police are here. Person A: Oh Man! What a bringdown!

Answer (score 0):

You could say that the addict **came to.** "To come to" means to regain consciousness or to return to one's usual state.

A note: the verb "come to" is intransitive in this sense; "to" is a particle rather than a preposition.